# sequelize findOrCreate transaction

Tags: transactions, sequelize.js

I am using Sqlite 3 *(4.0.6)* with Sequalize *(4.38.0)*. Models are Tournament what hasMany Season (unique index year and tournamentId). Here is the flush class:

```
  async flush(tournamentJSON) {
    this.tournamentJSON = tournamentJSON
    const {sequelize} = await this.orm
    this.transaction = await sequelize.transaction()
    try {
      const tournament = await this.flushTournament()
      const season = await this.flushSeason(tournament)
      // commit
      await this.transaction.commit();

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      // Rollback transaction if any errors were encountered
      if (err) await this.transaction.rollback();
    }
  }

  async flushTournament() {
    const {tournamentJSON} = this
    const {models: {Tournament}} = await this.orm
    const [tournament, created] = await Tournament.findOrCreate({
      where: {
        country: tournamentJSON.country,
        type: tournamentJSON.type,
        identifier: tournamentJSON.identifier
      },
      transaction: this.transaction
    })
    return tournament

  }

  async flushSeason(tournament) {
    const {tournamentJSON} = this
    const {models: {Season}} = await this.orm
    const [season, created] = await Season.findOrCreate({
      where: {
        name: tournamentJSON.name,
        finCommit: tournamentJSON.finCommit,
        start: moment(tournamentJSON.start.replace(/\./g, '-')).toISOString(),
        year: Number(this.year),
        tournamentId: tournament.id
      },
      transaction: this.transaction
    })
    console.log(created)
    console.log(season)
    return season
  }
```

And here is how I use it in my test:

```
  const flush = new Flush()
  const flush1 = new Flush()
  flush.year = 2011
  flush1.year = 2012
  let tournamentJSON = await Helper.loadJSON(`${t.context.fixtures}/someTournament.json`)
  await flush.flush(tournamentJSON)
  await flush1.flush(tournamentJSON)
```

I expect one tournament and two seasons (with year 2011 and 2012) to be created, but only one season is created, with the year 2012.
The `flushSeason` method runs twice. In two lines of `console.log` I can see, that in booth case `created` is true.

From the log:

```
Executing (cb4f89f4-8e00-4fd0-b329-0c263f389922): 
INSERT INTO `season` (`id`,`name`,`year`,`start`,`finished`,`scraped`,`finCommit`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`tournamentId`) 
VALUES (NULL,'Some name',2011,'2011-08-12 00:00:00.000 +00:00',0,0,'2000','2019-08-23 15:26:02.528 +00:00','2019-08-23 15:26:02.528 +00:00',1);
Executing (2ee2b03e-b127-491e-9da7-572e89d2ba70): 
INSERT INTO `season` (`id`,`name`,`year`,`start`,`finished`,`scraped`,`finCommit`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`tournamentId`) 
VALUES (NULL,'Some name',2012,'2011-08-12 00:00:00.000 +00:00',0,0,'2000','2019-08-23 15:26:02.528 +00:00','2019-08-23 15:26:02.528 +00:00',1);
```

Comment: What is "flush"?

Comment: flush is a class. see first code snippet. It has the flush method which "flushes" the JSON object to the database.

Comment: Ah, it's a "class" in the old es5 sense, right?

Comment: Looks like your code is missing the prototype bindings between the functions, no?

Comment: it is a class in es6 sense: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods

Comment: I really think you should find a way to be much more concise in your question, without all these complications, otherwise you'll have a hard time finding help...